# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureAD.Contracts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013

Was trying to follow the tutorial of MVC in ASP.NET site [Creating an Entity Framework Data Model for an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application), using [Visual Studio Express for Web 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-2013-express), here is an image of the version:
[image]

and just at the beginning I got this error when trying to select No Authentication:
[image: Change Authentication window]
[image: Error when select No Authentication]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to need to install Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013).

Go to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads, and click the "VS 2013 Install" link under .NET.

This will open Microsoft's WPI (Web Platform Installer), which will take you through the steps needed to install it.